# How to start automated testing a large application?

Tags: .net, database, automated-tests

EDIT : Thanks to the ncie commenters, I get the difference between unit and automated testing, so I renamed the topic

Environement : .net 2.0, sql server 2005,windows server 2003

I read this article :

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/convince.aspx

This guy is speaking about how you can add automated testing to an existing app without changng everything.

And I have to say that this article is really awesome, and make me wanna try it !

So our system is nearly the same : all the datas are accessible through web services, so we can easily (with soapui for instance) do some automated testing against these web servcies.

BUT : what about the database ? To do some automated testing, we need to have the correct data in the database corresponding to the automated test.

For instance, if I want to do a automated test checking that the software raises an error if the client's name is empty, I'll need to add, in my db, a client with an empty name.

here is how I think I can do it :

- create a server with everything it needs (iis, sql server...)
- add something so the date of this server never change so I don't have to change the time in my automated test
- add in my database the records I need to do my automated test

PROBLEM : the database will be a big mess in after 10 automated test, and I'll never know which record is for which automated test.
The idea would be to add a "TEST_NAME" column to every table, but it's a bit dirty in my mind.

So have you ever tried that kind of technique ? Did you use some specific tools ? Is my way of thinking the good one ? (or at least a good one).

Thanks

EDIT : I got 2 -1 for this thread, I'd like to know why so I won't do the same mistake twice.

Comment: You want to do more unit testing (use Mocks and Fakes in place of real database) and less system level testing that will frequently break because these tests depend heavily on environment and real database with specific records in it.  This will be more of a challenge for you, since you haven't written your tests first before development.  The Michael Feathers book, Working Effectively with Legacy Code, can help with your scenario.

Comment: @remi - you might consider changing 'unit test' to 'automated test.' Unit tests are isolated from external resources like databases, file systems, and networks.

Comment: @Jeff : here I want to test only my business layer (=web service), not my database, but I have to add test data in my database to make it work. @Chris O : As Omar says in the article, here the objective is to write only unit test, our code is not ready for mocking (and the developers too), so I think we have to use our database.

Comment: @Remi, you will have way more pain supporting system tests by fixing a broken environment and staging database, than by learning how to mock.  This is from my experience.

Comment: I agree with the commenters above. If you are trying to take your integration tests to the next level, ask about how to do better integration tests. Asking about how to improve handing of your database during your unit testing makes it look like you don't know what unit testing means yet.

Comment: I don't really know what are unit test indeed, I just read this article : I need automated test to  be able to save sometimes to me and the QA team. Mock is really a good idea, but : my colleague won't understand why there is an interface in parameters, why I'm not calling directly our static classes to get the data ... And I think that's an important criteria.

Answer (score 2):

If your unit tests are hitting your persistence layer you may actually be doing something akin to integration testing.  What you should do it abstract your database away during the unit test so that you are only test the logic and not that actually persistence medium. This allows you to focus on the business layer logic. This is easier said than done since it depends on the architecture of your data layer.

Data layers are often a simple matter of push in and pull out so lets say you can abtract your data layer into an interface like:

```
interface IRepository
{
   GetModel(id);
   SaveModel(model);
}
```

Then in your unit test to can stub/mock out your data layer with this interface. This way you tell the stub of your database to return any value you want and you can write a test that assets the expected behavior when that happens.

Comment: I think I didn't understand what unit test was all about (even though I read a lot about it, knwo that I'm in a real life case I got it). So I changed a bit the topic. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There maybe better solution than the one I am thinking about, but why not use a different database for unit testing and purge all content in preparation of another test cycle.

Comment: That's what I' thinking about : but the problem is the managing of this database, and how I can identify to which unit test is linked a record.

Comment: Different file based datasets for each *automated* test. I've dbUnit in the past. At the start of each test destroy the world and then build up only the dataset required. http://www.dbunit.org/bestpractices.html#nocleanup  *edit:* Changed "unit" to "automated". Personally I don't think you are "unit testing" but rather "function" or "integration" testing (they need to be done too so don't feel bad about it).

Comment: tests with another database are still integration tests.  The payback on unit tests happens when your tests break their dependency on the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you can generate your test data before each batch of tests then have your records start at an ID equal to the next number divisible by 100. So if the largest record is 350, generate starting a 400 and test with 400 and above.  When your DB gets really big, delete every thing.